# Display recent posts from portfolio

Tags: posts

I want to show the recent posts from the portfolio. 
I tried display-posts plugin, I also tried catposts plugin, but all they do is they show the recent posts just from the blog and ignore the portfolio posts. As far as I understand, the portfolio is an extension to blog but for some reason, it doesn't work...

Comment: Please post some of the code that you have tried.

Comment: portfolio posts are mostly maintained like custom post types, it depends on theme you are using..

Answer (score 1):

You can get latest post from any post type with the simple query

```
<?php
// Arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Or if you want show latest portfolio posts in the widget, you can use the below plugin:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/